# Getting the presence using UCMA 3.0

Tags: c#, .net, lync, ucma

I am using UCMA 3.0 . I just the user's presence by passing the useremailid and the domain of the user.
There is no clear information microsoft msdn site for this.

Can anyone please tell me the method?

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't very clear but as an experienced user of the UCMA API I'm going to make a stab at answering.

It appears that you want to subscribe to the presence of a user using their username and the domain name of the user.  For clarity you will need the actual SIP address of the users you want the presence of or a meaningful way to infer it.  The useremailID and domain of the user probably isn't a reliable way of inferring the SIP address.

For details on managing user presence via UCMA I recommend that you look into the `RemotePresenceView` class as documented here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.rtc.collaboration.presence.remotepresenceview_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncuc3cr(v=office.14).aspx

As with all things UCMA it's implementation is none trivial however there is lots of information on the MSDN site on how to implement it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh527743(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Please spare few more mins .... I am quite confused. My requirement is quite simple , I want to know whether "sampledomain/a.gmail.com" is available or offline . That's it .I am not understanding enpoints and other things here .

Comment: If we use ActiveXObject and if we just pass GetStatus(a@gmail.com) , I will get status as Active. Similar thing I need that's all